# How do you compile OpenCV with cmake?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile OpenCV so that it has the the sift module.

I downloaded CMake using [this tutorial](https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-cmake-on-centos-8/).

I also downloaded and unzipped opencv-4.3.0 and opencv_contrib.

I made an empty folder, opened the terminal, and navigated to it using the following line:

```
cd ~/opencvMaster/build
```

Then, while I was in this empty folder in the terminal, I ran the following line:

```
cmake -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH= ~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules ~/openCVMaster/opencv-4.3.0
```

It configured and generated the files.  I then input `make`. Got the following error:

```
[ 82%] Building CXX object modules/xfeatures2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_xfeatures2d.dir/src/boostdesc.cpp.o
~/opencvMaster/opencv_contrib-e6f32c6a69043456a806a4e802ee3ce7b7059c93/modules/xfeatures2d/src/boostdesc.cpp:654:20: fatal error: boostdesc_bgm.i: No such file or directory
           #include "boostdesc_bgm.i"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I followed the suggestion found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2427), and added the following files:

```
cd ~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-4.3.0/modules/xfeatures2d/src
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_lbgm.i >boostdesc_lbgm.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_binboost_256.i >boostdesc_binboost_256.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_binboost_128.i >boostdesc_binboost_128.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_binboost_064.i >boostdesc_binboost_064.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_bgm_hd.i >boostdesc_bgm_hd.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_bgm_bi.i >boostdesc_bgm_bi.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/34e4206aef44d50e6bbcd0ab06354b52e7466d26/boostdesc_bgm.i >boostdesc_bgm.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/fccf7cd6a4b12079f73bbfb21745f9babcd4eb1d/vgg_generated_120.i > vgg_generated_120.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/fccf7cd6a4b12079f73bbfb21745f9babcd4eb1d/vgg_generated_64.i >vgg_generated_64.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/fccf7cd6a4b12079f73bbfb21745f9babcd4eb1d/vgg_generated_48.i >vgg_generated_48.i
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/fccf7cd6a4b12079f73bbfb21745f9babcd4eb1d/vgg_generated_80.i >vgg_generated_80.i
```

This was a step forward: no more errors relating to vgg or boostdesc.  A new error appeared: `opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/test_features2d.cpp:51:10: fatal error: features2d/test/test_detectors_regression.impl.hpp: No such file or directory`

Following the advice of ah-ma [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2427)) I downloaded `https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules`. Once downloaded, I located its subfolder 'features2d' and put it in `opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/`.

Still got an error -

```
~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_converters.cpp:2:10: fatal error: common.h: No such file or directory
 #include "common.h"
```

I added the following:

```
cd ~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp
curl wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ray-project/common/master/common.h > common.h
```

I ran `make` again, and got the following errors:

```
~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_converters.cpp: In function ‘void Mat_to_vector_KeyPoint(cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&)’:
~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_converters.cpp:7:38: error: ‘LOGD’ was not declared in this scope
 #define CHECK_MAT(cond) if(!(cond)){ LOGD("FAILED: " #cond); return; }

~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_converters.cpp:14:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_MAT’
     CHECK_MAT(mat.type()==CV_32FC(7) && mat.cols==1);
     ^~~~~~~~~
~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_converters.cpp: In function ‘void Mat_to_vector_DMatch(cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&)’:
~/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/test/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_converters.cpp:7:38: error: ‘LOGD’ was not declared in this scope
 #define CHECK_MAT(cond) if(!(cond)){ LOGD("FAILED: " #cond); return; }
```

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: All steps you describe should be handled by CMake, including file downloads. Do you have to build java bindings? Go through your OpenCV options via `cmake -i`

Comment: @mainactual - thank you very much for helping.  To answer your question - I do not need java.  I tried to delete the folder in features2d called java (this raised an error relating to a new missing file) and I also ran cmake with -D WITH_JAVA=OFF (this raised the same error as above - void mat_to_vector in the features2d_converters.cpp file). I will try cmake -i.

Comment: To be more specific, here was the actual cmake I tried last: cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=//home/kate/Documents/openCVMaster/opencv_contrib-master/modules /home/kate/Documents/openCVMaster/opencv-4.3.0

Comment: [binary-folder]/modules/core/version_string.inc lists build options, so you can check or append here. It is not adviced to hand tailor the build, but rather let the CMake do it. So I'd make a clean folder, walk through all options with `cmake -i`and let CMake download the files. After you know the options, build the one line command with `-D`s. Also, when you add contrib-modules, they are all enabled by default (and some trickier to compile) whereas you only need xfeatures2d.

Comment: @mainactual.  You really helped me. `cmake -i` appears to be deprecated in my version of cmake, but tried I cmake-gui, which allows me to check the modules that I want.  I followed your advice and removed everything but features2d and enable_nonfree.  Happily, the compile arrive all the way to the end without fatal errors :-)  The only problem now is that I have a new bunch of errors that say it can't link the CXX module, (which I think is necessary for python) and that I need to recompile with fPIC.

Comment: ps, if you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll vote it up.

Comment: I figured out which boxes I needed to tick in cmake-gui (BUILD_opencv_core, BUILD_cv_features2d, BUILD_opencv_flann, BUILD_opencv_imgproc, [everything with python in the name], ENABLE_CCACHE, OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE, ENABLE_PIC) and now have a complete compiled python module. Thank you very much @mainactual - I was working on this for about a month with no success and was about to give up.  Tomorrow I'll try to figure how to get vscode to recognize my new opencv module :-)

Comment: Great :) As I saw Linux, thought you are working on terminal only. cmake-gui is of course what I typically use.

Answer (score 1):

- Download `opencv-4.3.0.zip` and `opencv_contrib-4.3.0.zip.`  Unzip them.
- Open `opencv_contrib-4.3.0\modules.`  Copy the folder that says `xfeatures2d`.  Open `opencv-4.3.0\modules`, and paste the folder just copied (`xfeatures2d`)
- Make an empty folder, and call it 'Build45.'
- Open cmake-gui.
- In the box that says, 'Where to build the binaries' put the file path representing your empty folder (`Build45`)
- In the box that says, 'Where is the source code' put the file path representing `opencv-4.3.0.`

[image]

- Click `configure.`  Choices will appear.
- Input 'free' into the search box and check the box that says OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE.
- Input `xfeatures2d` and check the box that says 'Build_opencv_xfeatures2d`
- Click `configure` again. (Doublecheck you've done this right: there is a second box in cmake gui that gives build details.  You should see `Non-free algorithms: YES`.
- Click `Generate`.
- Check that the build45 folder is now filled with stuff.
- Open your terminal and navigate to the build45 folder (`cd ~/opencv-master/build45`)
- Type `cmake .`
- Type `make`
- NOTE:* It will take a couple hours to compile.  Make yourself a cup of tea*.
- Type `sudo make install`
- Check that it worked: in your terminal, type `python3`
- Type `import cv2`
- Type `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`
- You should get no errors.  If you do get errors, the following troubleshooting tools may be helpful:

```
import cv2
print cv2.getBuildInformation()
```

```
import cv2
funcs = dir(cv2)
for f in funcs:
...     print(f)
```

Also, if you are worried about infringing patents, check here for discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/computervision/comments/ba1l8g/according_to_this_the_patent_on_sift_was_due_to/

Answer (score 1):

```
# Step 1: Install VS 2017 for cmake 
 # Step 2: Install CMake
```

Download and install CMake v3.10.0 from https://cmake.org/download/.
[image]

During installation select “Add CMake to system PATH”

[image]

```
# step 3: install Anaconda
# step 4: Download and extract opencv-3.3.1 and opencv_contrib-3.3.1
Go to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases and download opencv-3.3.1 source code zip
```

[image]

Go to https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases and download opencv_contrib-3.3.1 source code zip
[image]

Extract both zip files. Although you can keep opencv and opencv_contrib folders anywhere, I suggest that you should keep both in the same directory. I have placed these two folders in “My Documents” directory.

NOTE : From hereon we will refer the path to opencv-3.3.1 folder as OPENCV_PATH. For example, in my case OPENCV_PATH is C:/Users/Vaibhaw Chandel/Documents/opencv-3.3.1

Depending upon where you have kept opencv-3.3.1 folder, this path would be different.

[image]

## Step 5: Generate Visual Studio project using CMake

Run Cmake, in box “Where is the source code” write value of OPENCV_PATH (which is path to opencv-3.3.1 folder) and path to build directory. We will choose build directory as OPENCV_PATH/build

[image]

Now click configure.
You will be asked for permission to create the build folder. Click Yes
[image]

When prompted to select a compiler, select Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64.
[image]

Click finish and in the next window keep the default parameters checked.
[image]

Click finish. Now CMake will look in the system directories and generate the makefiles.

## Step 5.1: Additional changes to CMake config

We will make few changes in the default configuration generated by CMake. Click on the images to see a larger version.

Check “INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES” and “INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES”
In flag “OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH”, give path of modules directory within opencv_contrib-3.3.1. In our case we have kept opencv_contrib-3.3.1 in Documents folder so path is “C:/Users/Vaibhaw Chandel/Documents/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules”
Now click configure to apply these changes.
[image]

On Windows 10, opencv_saliency module fails to build. So we will disable it. Uncheck BUILD_opencv_saliency
Now click on configure again to include this change.

## Step 5.2 : Add Python paths for both Python2 and Python3 (optional)

This section is only for people who want to generate OpenCV binary for both Python2 and Python 3. If you are going to use just one Python either 2 or 3, you should skip this section.

CMake was unable to find paths for my Python3 files.

[image]
So I manually added paths for Python3
[image]
Now click configure again. After configuring is done, search opencv_python in search bar, both BUILD_opencv_python2 and BUILD_opencv_python3 will be automatically checked. Now we are sure that OpenCV binaries for both Python2 and Python 3 will be generated after compilation.
[image]

## Step 5.3 : Generate build files

If CMake is able to configure without any errors it should say “Configuring done”.
Click generate.

Note: Whenever you make any changes(check/uncheck boxes or change path) to configuration generated by CMake, always click configure and generate.

## Step 6: Compile OpenCV

## Step 6.1:Compile opencv in Release mode

Open Windows Command Prompt (cmd).
Go to OPENCV_PATH/build directory and run this command
1

```
cmake.exe --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
```

## Step 6.2 : Compile opencv in Debug mode

Open CMake GUI again as mentioned in Step 5.

Search “python” in search box
Uncheck INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES, BUILD_opencv_python3 and BUILD_opencv_python2
Click configure
Click generate
Now in windows command prompt
Go to OPENCV_PATH/build directory and run this command

1

```
cmake.exe --build . --config Debug --target INSTALL
```

Now that we have compiled OpenCV we will find out how to test a OpenCV project using CMake.

## Step 7: Update System Environment Variables

## Step 7.1 : Update environment variable – PATH

## Step 7.2 : Update user environment variable – OPENCV_DIR

Comment: If you read the question properly, you'll noticed, that he already could build using cmake. But I guess it is still nice of you to document that whole steps.